# how to configure redirect in DeleteView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

when i try to delete some comment it first take me to the comment_delete_confirm.html, then redirect to the page what linked in success_url = '/blog/'. Problem become when i change success_url to something like 'post-detail' (becose i want after comment_delete_confirm return to the post), it cannot find this page, becose in the brauser url it looks like that: '127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post/18/comment_delete/post-detail'

this is my views.py and urls.py files:

```
class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    success_url = 'post-detail'
    # only the author can delete his post
    # if not author try to delete post it gives 403 forbidden
    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.user:
            return True
        return False

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', add_comment, name='comment-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment_update/', comment_update, name='comment-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment_delete/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment-delete')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the actual URL, not the name. You can use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) for this.

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post-detail')
```

**Edit**

If you need dynamic data, you can override the `get_success_url` method instead of defining the attribute directly. There you have access to `self.object` (because the method is called before the deletion is actually processed). Assuming your comment object has a `post` field which is a foreign key to Post:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.post_id})
```

Comment: i'm got issue: 'Reverse for 'post-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/post\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']'. i sink i must add 'pk' to the 'success_url' but but how?